# docker network create for QGIS server - [protocol not available]

Tags: docker, nginx, qgis, docker-run

I try to run qgis-server and on pushing below command I get the error and it stops on the last file in bash. I am using Windows 11 with WSL2

```bash
docker network create qgis
docker run -d --rm --name qgis-server --net=qgis --hostname=qgis-server \
              -v $(pwd)/data:/data:ro -p 5555:5555 \
              -e "QGIS_PROJECT_FILE=/data/osm.qgs" \
              qgis-server
```

Output error:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x58 pc=0x55bc0ba3b380]

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/docker/cli/vendor/github.com/docker/docker/client.(*Client).ClientVersion(0xc0004c80f0?)
        /go/src/github.com/docker/cli/vendor/github.com/docker/docker/client/client.go:237
github.com/docker/cli/cli/command.(*DockerCli).CurrentVersion(0xc0004c80f0)
        /go/src/github.com/docker/cli/cli/command/cli.go:99 +0x36
main.areSubcommandsSupported(0xc00013a300, {0x55bc0c51d808, 0xc0004c80f0})
        /go/src/github.com/docker/cli/cmd/docker/docker.go:451 +0xc6
main.isSupported(0x55bc0ba7d391?, {0x55bc0c51d808, 0xc0004c80f0})
        /go/src/github.com/docker/cli/cmd/docker/docker.go:395 +0x28
main.setValidateArgs.func1.1(0xc00013a300?, {0xc000192f00, 0x1, 0x1})
        /go/src/github.com/docker/cli/cmd/docker/docker.go:183 +0x65
github.com/docker/cli/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ValidateArgs(...)
        /go/src/github.com/docker/cli/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:1096
github.com/docker/cli/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute(0xc00013a300?, {0xc0002a0380?, 0x1?, 0x1?})
        /go/src/github.com/docker/cli/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:909 +0x653
github.com/docker/cli/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC(0xc000004300)
        /go/src/github.com/docker/cli/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:1068 +0x3bd
github.com/docker/cli/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute(...)
        /go/src/github.com/docker/cli/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:992
main.runDocker(0x0?)
        /go/src/github.com/docker/cli/cmd/docker/docker.go:263 +0x4b7
main.main()
        /go/src/github.com/docker/cli/cmd/docker/docker.go:274 +0x97
Failed to initialize: protocol not available
```

I don´t know what the problem could be, I was doing the current tutorial: https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/server_manual/containerized_deployment.html firstly for NGINX and then docker.